# Install and run issue with this "Yarn npm error"

Tags: npm, installation, yarnpkg

```
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % sudo yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts start
/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts build
/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % yarn run kyawlinoo
yarn run v1.22.19
error Command "kyawlinoo" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % npm run build

> dashboard@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

sh: react-scripts: command not found
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % npm run build

> dashboard@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

sh: react-scripts: command not found
kyawlinoo@min-htet-oo Dashboard-starter % npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: dashboard@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-circular-progressbar@2.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-circular-progressbar
npm ERR!   react-circular-progressbar@"^2.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See /Users/kyawlinoo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kyawlinoo/.npm/\_logs/2022-11-24T15_53_11_703Z-debug-0.log
```

I want to install yarn and make it work to go for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use this for windows:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

Or Arch Linux:

```
pacman -S yarn
```

Make sure you have the latest version of Node.js

More installation instructions are here:
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#arch-stable